# IP authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ip

I'd like to know if this is possible? I have a client who would like to add a seperate login with IP authentication, however from my understanding most service providers don't generate static IP's for it's users.

How would this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if `request.remote_ip` is within those addresses matching your requirements.